# IIS App Pool keeps timing out even with the recommended settings to prevent it

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET 4.5.1 application running in IIS 8.5 on 2012 R2 Server that I need to always be "Alive" and never get the first hit startup/JIT penalty. From my research on here I think I've made the IIS settings that are intended to prevent this:

[image]

But checking IIS logs I keep seeing these entries after hitting the site after about 20 minutes of idle time:

```
> #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
> #Version: 1.0
> #Date: 2015-06-23 00:00:16
```

Which apparently indicates the app pool has restarted (Am I correct on that?)

I've checked the App and System Event viewer logs and don't see any app pool restarts or unhandled exceptions getting logged from my app, but the app definitely has a startup delay after about 20 minutes.

Any ideas on what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Have you double-checked your `Recycling` settings?

Have you set the `Regular Time Interval` to zero?

You can also enable more recycle event logging, maybe that helps.

The

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 8.5
```

header don't necessarily mean a AppPool restart, certain configuration changes trigger that too.